# Yii how to redirect to absolute URL with json response

Tags: php, yii, yii-extensions

**My Controler**

```
function actionLogin()
{
     //After success validation
     $url = $_POST['returnUrl']; // www.example.com/get_response/
     $arr = array('response' => 'Failed', 'msg' => 'login success','tokenKey'=> 'token');

    //How to send the response to url

}
```

> In my above code i have to send the $arr array to $url absolute URL.

**I found some  solutions for this is it works here?**

```
Yii::$app->getResponse()->redirect('http://newdomain.com');
```

> But i don't know how to use in my case  or is there any better way

Comment: Why cant you just return your value as a normal http response

Comment: @ Dinistro yes normal http response

Comment: I really do not get your problem? Did you read this? http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CController#redirect-detail What is your problem? Do you want redirect your user and give to this redirect URL parameters?

Answer (score 4):

In controller, use:

```
$this->redirect("absolute URL");
```

If you want redirect to a specific action:

```
$this->redirect(array('controller/action'));
```

Comment: But he can't redirect and send the `$arr`

Comment: If we use string that is absolute URL

Answer (score 2):

we can use getBaseUrl  to get absolute url

```
$this->redirect(Yii::app()->getRequest()->getBaseUrl(true));
```

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/19649-redirect-to-external-website/) you can read how to redirect in Yii.

Following code should work for you:

```
function actionLogin()
{
     //After success validation
     $url = $_POST['returnUrl']; // www.example.com/get_response/
     $arr = array('response' => 'Failed', 'msg' => 'login success', 'tokenKey' => 'token');

     //How to send the response to url
     $this->redirect('http://' . $url . '?' . http_build_query($arr));
}
```

You have to build your http query by your own. Yii does not support any function that helps you to create outbound urls with query parameters.